# Для чего используется RESULT_OK и getBooleanExtra?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Есть код дочерней активности, которая получает информацию от главной, затем возвращает в главную активность информацию о том, нажимал ли пользователь кнопку для получения этой информации:

```
  public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE =
                "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true"; // ключ для получения дополнения с правильным ответом
        private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN =
                "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_shown"; // ключь для передачи данных о том, видел ли пользовательно ответ

        private boolean mAnswerIsTrue; // правильный ответ

        private TextView mAnswerTextView;
        private Button mShowAnswerButton;

        public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) { // с помощью этого метода главная активность передаёт данные в дочернию
            Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
            return intent;
        }

        public static boolean wasAnswerShown(Intent result) { // упрощае декодирование данных к виду, который может использовать QuizActivity (с 129)
            return result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false); // getBooleanExtra - метод для чтения значения из дополнения
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

            mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false); // получение данных из intent

            mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);

            mShowAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
            mShowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                        mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                    } else {
                        mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                    }
                    setAnswerShownResult(true);
                }
            });
        }

        private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) { // возвращает в главную активность информацию о том, подсматривал ли пользователь ответ
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown); // передайт true, если пользовательно подсматривал ответ (вторая переменная)
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data); // возвращает данные в главную активность
        }
    }
```

Меня интересуют 2 метода:

Метод:

```
public static boolean wasAnswerShown(Intent result) { // упрощае декодирование данных к виду, который может использовать QuizActivity (с 129)
                return result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false); // getBooleanExtra - метод для чтения значения из дополнения
            }
```

И метод:

```
 private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) { // возвращает в главную активность информацию о том, подсматривал ли пользователь ответ
                        Intent data = new Intent();
                        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown); // передайт true, если пользовательно подсматривал ответ (вторая переменная)
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, data); // возвращает данные в главную активность
                    }
                }
```

При удалении любого из этих методов, при возвращении на главную активность перестаёт выводится сообщение о том, что пользователь нажал на кнопку с правильным ответом. Однако я не понимаю в чём заключается взаимодополняющая роль эти методов, мне кажется, что они делают примерно одно и то же.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делают эти методы (так как я видимо ошибаюсь в этом) и как они между собой связаны

Код главной активности:

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index"; // ключ, нужный для сохранения значения индекса мнежду поворотами сматрфона
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT = 0;

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Button mCheatButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] { // так как этот массив ссылвется на объект класса Question,
            //я могу вызывать из него методы класса Question
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
    private boolean mIsCheater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0); // извлечение сохранённого индекса из Bundle,
            // если он существует (не равен null)
        }

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Изучить тему анонимных классов и слушателей
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                mIsCheater = false;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
        mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start CheatActivity
                boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
                Intent intent = CheatActivity.newIntent(QuizActivity.this, answerIsTrue);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT); // не только отправляет информацию, но и получает обратную связь
            }
        });

        updateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // метод, с помощью которого активность узнаёт, жёльничал ли пользователь
                                                                                    //для того, чтобы, если он жульничал, поменять значение во всплывающем окне
                                                                                    // на "Cheating is wrong.", это происходит в методе checkAnswer
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            mIsCheater = CheatActivity.wasAnswerShown(data); // если пользователь жульничал, переменной mIsCheater присваивается значение true
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex); // сохранение индекса в Bundle
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }

    private void updateQuestion() { // вставляет в TextView вопрос в соответствии с его индексом
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
        int messageResId = 0;
        if (mIsCheater) {
            messageResId = R.string.judgment_toast;
        } else {
            if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
                messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
            } else {
                messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
            }
        }
            Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    }
}
```

Класс Question:

```
public class Question {
    private int mTextResId;
    private boolean mAnswerTrue;

    public Question(int textResId, boolean answerTrue) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }

    public int getTextResId() {
        return mTextResId;
    }

    public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
    }

    public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
        return mAnswerTrue;
    }

    public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }

}
```

P.S. в комментариях я попытался указать своё понимание того, что происходит в коде

Comment: Да, код главной активности тут явно необходим.  Метод wasAnswerShown вызывается именно из нее, без кода главной активности непонятна (частично) логика.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, главная активность добавлена

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html, https://metanit.com/java/android/2.11.php, https://medium.com/chewing-android-for-beginners/startactivityforresult-db64dba94093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С добавлением кода главной активности все, вроде бы, стало понятно.

Если в двух словах, то методы `wasAnswerShown` и `setAnswerShownResult` являются getter'ом и setter'ом соответственно. То есть `setAnswerShownResult` позволяет сохранить значение (пока будем считать, что просто где-то сохранить), а метод `wasAnswerShown` - получить значение, которое сохранил `setAnswerShownResult`.

Теперь о том, как именно это происходит у Вас.

Сначала главная активность запускает CheatActivity:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT);
```

Если в CheatActivity пользователь нажимает на кнопку, то вызывается метод setAnswerShownResult:

```
private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown); 
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
}
```

Строка `Intent data = new Intent();` - создаем Intent, думаю тут вопросов нет.

Строка `data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);` - добавляем в созданный выше Intent информацию. Храним информацию по ключу `EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN` (это как номер ячейки в банке, без него не найдем то, что сохранили).

Строка `setResult(RESULT_OK, data);` завершить активность с результатом `RESULT_OK` (то есть сигнализируем, что ошибок нет) и вернуть в MainActivity data (наш Intent с данными).

После вызова `setResult` CheatActivity уничтожается. Запускается MainActivity, система вызывает метод `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        mIsCheater = CheatActivity.wasAnswerShown(data); 
    }
}
```

Теперь снова разбор по строкам:

```
if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    return;
}
```

`resultCode` будет равен `RESULT_OK`  только если мы вызвали `setAnswerShownResult`. Соответственно, если не равен - то делать ничего не надо.

`if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT)` - проверяем, что произошел возврат именно из `CheatActivity`.

Этот же ключик `REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT` мы использовали при запуске `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT);`

В реальных приложениях можно встретить ситуацию, когда возврат возможен с доброго десятка активностей, так что за кодом `REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT` надо привыкать следить. Для каждой активности код, конечно, должен быть уникален.

```
if (data == null) {
    return;
}
```

Тут, вроде, все понятно. Если данных нет, то и делать ничего не надо.

```
mIsCheater = CheatActivity.wasAnswerShown(data);
```

Мы пришли к вызову `wasAnswerShown`. По сути, метод просто достает данные из data.

Рассмотрим его код:

```
public static boolean wasAnswerShown(Intent result) {
    return result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false); 
}
```

`result` - это то, что раньше называлось `data`.

`result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);` - Пытаемся найти значение типа `bool` по ключу `EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN`.

Подытожу:

1. `Activity.RESULT_OK` позволяет указать, что активность завершилась нормально, без ошибок.
2. `getBooleanExtra` - позволяет получить из `Intent` ранее сохраненное значение типа `bool` по ключу

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!